# Select de dos tablas no relacioandas

Tags: symfony3, dql

Soy nuevo en `Symfony` y me ha surgido un problema con una consulta. Tengo dos entidades no relacionadas directamente: **vacation** y **absence** y ambas tienen un campo 'approved' que por defecto esta a 0. Lo que quiero es recuperar todos los registros cuyo campo `approved` este a 0. Utilizo esta consulta:

```
SELECT v, a
FROM AppBundle:Vacation v, AppBundle:Absence a
WHERE v.approved = 0 AND a.approved = 0');
```

Y funciona perfectamente mientras haya en ambas al menos un registro con el campo `approved` a 0. Si en una de ellas no hay ningún registro a 0 no me devuelve nada. Y si le pongo un `OR` en lugar del `AND` en esas mismas circunstancias me devuelve todos los registros aunque estén a 1. Habría alguna forma de conseguir el resultado con una sola consulta?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al no estar relacionadas, lo que puedes hacer es realizar las consultas por separado, y 'juntar' la respuesta.

De hecho, lo puedes hacer mediante el ORM, sin necesidad de hacer la consulta SQL:

```html
<?php
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $vacations = $em->getReposiotry('AppBundle:Vacation')->findByApproved(false);
  $absences = $em->getReposiotry('AppBundle:Vacation')->findByApproved(false);
  
  $result = new ArrayCollection(
    array_merge(
      $vacations, 
      $absences
    )
  );
```

Ahora, en $result, tendras un ArrayCollection con el resultado de las dos consultas, y en el caso de que en alguna no exista el registro, obtendrás los resultados de la otra.

Un saludo, espero que te sirva.